# Unable to compile index using OSCOLA bibliographic style

Tags: biblatex, indexing, texshop, imakeidx

I am trying to generate tables of cases and legislation in a document that cites legal materials. I am using [the OSCOLA style for BibLaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oscola) which generally works well. However, I am having difficulty inserting tables of cases etc. As the documentation for the style notes, in legal writing, these must come before the main text of the document, which is the opposite of normal behaviour. The style (I think) provides a command for this, \printindexearly, which should work but I continue to encounter an error:

```
! Package imakeidx Error: Misplaced \printindex[test].
```

Figuring this out is made somewhat more complicated by the fact that I cannot seem to customise the commands for indexing in TeXShop, so I am running makeindex from the command line.

This is a MWE:

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,    citereset=chapter, ibidtracker=true,          indexing=cite,         backend=biber,        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage[splitindex,            nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of Cases}]

\DeclareIndexAssociation{eucases}{cases}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\title{Test Document}
\begin{document}

\printindexearly{cases}

 Environmental protection was not mentioned as a policy goal or area of Community powers in the Treaty of Rome and therefore the European Council stated that environmental measures could be harmonised as part of efforts to equalise competitive conditions across the EEC, something which was later affirmed by the European Court of Justice.\autocite[]{C91/79}  

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@jurisdiction{C91/79,
title = {Commission v. Italy}, 
shorttitle = {Commission v. Italy}, 
shorthand = {C91/79}, 
volume = {}, 
number = {91/79}, 
keywords = {eu}, 
court = {}, 
journaltitle = {ECR}, 
series = {}, 
pages = {1099}, 
pagination = {}, 
options = {}, 
note = {}, 
additionalreports = {}, 
date = {1980}, 
location = {}
}
```

The command line I am using to generate the index file is:

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/splitindex test.idx -- -s oscola
```

Comment: I think, it is `\printindexearly[cases]`, according to the `imakeidx` syntax for splitted indices

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- That is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using `imakeidx` with the `splitindex` option, it is possible, to use several indexes. In order to know, which index entry goes to which index, one has to say `\index[indexA]{Entry}` etc. as well as the `\printindex[indexA]`, respectively `\printindexearly[cases]`.

The OP either made a typo or misused the syntax when he wrote `\printindexearly{cases}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,    citereset=chapter, ibidtracker=true,          indexing=cite,         backend=biber,        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
\usepackage[splitindex,            nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of Cases}]

\DeclareIndexAssociation{eucases}{cases}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\title{Test Document}
\begin{document}

\printindexearly{cases}

 Environmental protection was not mentioned as a policy goal or area of Community powers in the Treaty of Rome and therefore the European Council stated that environmental measures could be harmonised as part of efforts to equalise competitive conditions across the EEC, something which was later affirmed by the European Court of Justice.\autocite[]{C91/79}  

\end{document}
```